# SCSS not being applied to React Navbar

Tags: html, reactjs, sass

I have an issue I can't seem to understand. I have a scss stylt that is supposed to position the logo of my project to the middle of the screen. I'm able to manipulate the img itself but not it's position. I've tried changing the justification and deleting the display/ justify/ align-items entirely,

This issue is only applying to this section of the navbar. I've had this problem before but never solved it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Package JSON

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@sanity/client": "^3.3.0",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "framer-motion": "^6.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

SCSS

```
.app__navbar 
{

    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;

    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.18);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
}

.app__navbar-logo 

{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;

    img {
        width: 90px;
        height: 20px;

        @media screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
            width: 180px;
            height: 40px;
        }
    }
}
```

```
React
import './Navbar.scss'
const Navbar = () => {    
  return (
    <nav className="app__navbar">
      <div className="app__navbar-logo">
        <img src={images.logo} alt='logo'></img>
      </div>
      <ul className="app__navbar-links">
        {['home', 'about', 'work', 'skills', 'contact'].map((item) => (
          <li className='app__flex p-text' key={`link-${item}`}>
            <div></div>
            <a href={`#${item}`}>{item}</a>  
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Comment: What bundler are you using? CRA, webpack, vite, rollup, etc.

Comment: To my knowledge I haven't used a bundler, unless npm counts

Comment: Sounds strange, are you sure you're not using something like CRA or webpack? JSX has to be transpiled by something and unless you're manually compiling with babel this wouldn't work. How did you initialize your application? Feel free to @tag me so I get notified.

Comment: @Undo I had to uninstall react globally and reinstall using npx create-react-app to install the updated version. Is there a command i can run in terminal to identify if CRA or Webpack is being used?

I checked the package-lock.json and babel is included.

I've only messed with react for a few hours and have had this issue on other projects.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, CRA is "create-react-app" and it uses webpack internally. You can try running `npm install sass` usually that works better since this is client-side.

Comment: @Undo I appreciate your help, after watching the tutorial again the code is behaving as expected. The creator is using a much smaller display and that threw me off.